# Cookie logic for lightbox popup that triggers when hovers off page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to ask for a help about my project. I made a simple lightbox for advertising purposes. I wanted not to repeat the lightbox popup if it already popup once or once closed by the user.

Here's my html

```
    <div class="backdrop"></div>

<div class="box">
    <a class="close"><img src="/images/assets/close.png" width="35" height="35"/></a>

    <span class="lightbox-title">Wait... Before You Go!</span>
    <span class="lightbox-subtitle">You May Also Be Interested In...</span>


    <div class="brands-container">
        <a class="hyperlink" href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
            <div class="col-lg-4 brand">
                <img class="logo" src="/images/assets/mywebsite-logo.png"></img>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                <img class="screenshot" src="/images/assets/mywebsite-ss.jpg" width="320" height="150"/></img>

                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Visit Now</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a class="hyperlink" href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
            <div class="col-lg-4 brand">
                <img class="logo" src="/images/assets/mywebsite-logo.png"></img>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                <img class="screenshot" src="/images/assets/mywebsite-ss.jpg" width="320" height="150"/></img>

                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Visit Now</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>    

        <a class="hyperlink" href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
            <div class="col-lg-4 brand">
                <img class="logo" src="/images/assets/mywebsite-logo.png"></img>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                <img class="screenshot" src="/images/assets/mywebsite-ss.jpg" width="320" height="150"/></img>

                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Visit Now</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>      
</div>
```

This is my lightbox popup trigger

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('mouseleave', function() {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
            console.log('mouse left');
        });

        $('.close').click(function(){
            close_box();
        });

        $('.backdrop').click(function(){
            close_box();
        });
    });

    function close_box()
    {
        $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
        });
    }
</script>
```

My lightbox triggers when the cursor is off page. I wanted to have a logic that when the lightbox popup was already appeared once, it will not show on the 2nd view. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using one global variable as flag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lightBoxNotAppeared = true; // At the time of loading

    $(document).on('mouseleave', function() {

        if( lightBoxNotAppeared ){

            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
                'opacity': '.50'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({
                'opacity': '1.00'
            }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');

            console.log('mouse left');

            lightBoxNotAppeared = false; // change flag to false after lightbox appeared
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ravi -- is there any cookie involved?

Comment: @KobeBryan No, not using any cookies

Comment: Ravi -- but do I really need to have cookies for lightbox? Please enlighten me.

Comment: @KobeBryan I guess you are looking for a persistence way of hiding the add across the multiple sessions of  the user(correct me if wrong). In that case you can have flag in the table of user in DB of. Based this while loading the page you can control of display or not to display the add

Comment: Ravi -- I see. I wanted to store the values on the cookies not on DB.